# What does my TypeScript compiler compile?

Tags: typescript

I have the following tsconfig.json file

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "target": "es5"
   }
}
```

And single TypeScript file src/app/pages/details/testts.ts:

```
let x = 5;
```

When I run tsc from the folder where tsconfig.json placed I get this diagnostics:

```
D:\Workspaces\MyProject\client>tsc  src/app/pages/details/testts.ts --diagnostics
Files:               2
Lines:           19005
Nodes:           95663
Identifiers:     35490
Symbols:         94717
Types:           12063
Memory used:    92569K
I/O read:        0.00s
I/O write:       0.00s
Parse time:      0.35s
Bind time:       0.17s
Check time:      1.58s
Emit time:       0.03s
Total time:      2.12s
```

It says I have compiled two files with 19005 lines in total for 2.12s! 
I believe I have one file and one line in it. What has went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second file is `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts`. It contains type declarations for all the things that may exist in javascript runtime environment.

Try running

`tsc src/app/pages/details/testts.ts --diagnostics --noLib`

or just remove that file temporarily, then you will get report about just one file, as expected:

```
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Array'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Boolean'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Function'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'IArguments'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Number'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Object'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'RegExp'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'String'.
Files:               1
Lines:               1
Nodes:               7
Identifiers:         1
Symbols:             5
Types:              20
Memory used:    12438K
I/O read:        0.00s
I/O write:       0.00s
Parse time:      0.01s
Bind time:       0.00s
Check time:      0.00s
Emit time:       0.02s
Total time:      0.04s
```

It seems rather strange that typescript can not typecheck trivial example without having access to declarations for `Array` and others in separate file, but that's the way it is.

Also, there is `--lib` compiler option which selects what library files are included. For example, if you want to restrict available global symbols to es5 only, you can use

```
tsc src/app/pages/details/testts.ts --lib es5
```

which will use `node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es5.d.ts`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me to understand what is going on. But this basically means 2 seconds compile time for one line... And unfortunately, this same time is taken while recompile triggered by watch -w. Which means additional 2s before my tests start running. No way to safely increase performance?

Comment: To make it faster, you can use only a subset of the library that your code actually needs. On my computer, one-line file takes 0.24 s with `--lib es5`, 1.60s with `--lib es5,dom`, and about the same with default lib. You can create custom library file with only the definitions that you want, and use it with `tsc test.ts your-lib-file.d.ts --noLib`.